# Adjective for not first but either second, third, fourth, etc

Tags: adjectives, antonyms, ordinal-numbers

What is an adjective for something that is not first but either second, third, fourth, etc? We don't need to know what position it is at; the only thing that matters is that it's not the first one.

EDIT: 
After reading the comments/answers, I realized I didn't provide much context. Let's say I have a few words preceded by a prefix. The first prefix however is different than the others, so we say there are different prefixes for the **first** word and the **XXX** (later) words. What can we use for XXX?

Comment: "LATER" ? I know "latter" means the second of TWO but there might be more than two in my case

Comment: @Hi dominicbri7 and welcome to EL&U. No need to add thanks or your signature to your post - your user card is signature enough, and [signatures are actually discouraged](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) and edited out here on Stack Exchange sites since our questions and answers will hopefully be around for many future visitors :)

Comment: would it be Losers ??  More seriously, it's a good question.  What about simply "non-winners"?

Comment: @Joe: that only applies when it's about a contest of some kind. First, second, third can also apply to a simple ordering (or elements in a list, for example).

Comment: @joach Quite right, JS.  It's an interesting question, there needs to be an English word, something like, "Non-premier" ....

Comment: @Joe Blow - Yup. Here in America we call them `losers`. :-)

Comment: Well as Joach said, that only applies when there is something to be won, like a game or a contest, etc.
In my case it's only a simple ordering where A could be 1st or 8th, it doesn't really matter but I have to do specific processing for the one that is first, and another specific processing for everything else that is not first. That is why I chose **later**/**other**. But I feel like there should be a word solely for "not first" as Joe Blow said. It's kind of a first vs the rest thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It very much depends on context.

In many/most contexts, anything that's "not first" is just **subsequent**, or **later**.

In OP's context, the best word might be **other**. It's hard to say.

Comment: I supplied more context in the OP.
But indeed I think it would be **later**.

Comment: @dominicbri7: I've changed my answer, but I still don't really exactly understand your context.

Comment: That's because it is hard to explain, but later/other/subsequent all work I guess.

Comment: @dominicbri7: I think *subsequent* is best suited to contexts where the *complete actual sequence* is significant, and *later* fits better if only the fact of one particular word coming first is relevant. If even the fact of one word coming first isn't important in and of itself, *other* is probably best.

Answer (score 10):

Depending on context, you might consider *subsequent*.

> His first book was good, but the
>   subsequent ones were bad.
>
> His first wife was old, but the
>   subsequent ones were young.

Answer (score 0):

A term sometimes used in this context is "contender." That denotes someone who is not a winner or "champion," but "close." Perhaps a defeated party who was "up there."

Comment: The term "also ran" usually means a horse who was [not a win/place/show](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/also-rans), so in that sense it means "fourth place or later", not "second or later". In general use it tends to mean "so far behind (or so mediocre, etc.) as to be insignificant", so it's perhaps not the best word for the OP's question.