# What word is an adjective meaning "not first"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, terminology, ordinal-numbers

In the following sentences, what single word can I use to summarize the ordinal numbers second, third, fourth, etc.?

> When you take your second, third, fourth, etc. flu shot, call me.
>
> If you have your second, third, fourth, etc. dessert, you might get a stomach ache.
>
> When you have your second, third, fourth, etc. child, avail of this family planning class.

I've looked at [this related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33192/adjective-for-not-first-but-either-second-third-fourth-etc) but the words subsequent, later, other, and contender do not seem to fit this context.

In particular, taking the first example, using "subsequent" changes the object to plural.

> When you take your subsequent flu shot**s**, call me.

I'm looking for a word that keeps it in singular form as I am not referring to the whole set of flu shots after the first one, but rather to the specific second, or third, or fourth, etc. instance of that flu shot.

Comment: Your second sentence is quite strange. It does not sound like natural English. _When_ should probably be _if_, if you’re talking about having several different desserts with one meal (e.g., first cake, then ice cream). If you’re talking about having helping yourself to several servings of a single dessert (having a piece of cake, then another, then another), you wouldn’t say “your second dessert”. You’d most likely say something like, “You may get a stomach ache if you have extra helpings of dessert”.

Comment: Also, you can use _subsequent_ with singulars: “When you take any subsequent flu shot, call me” or “Call me whenever you take any subsequent flu shot” are both perfectly fine.

Comment: *"Next*" or "*another*" works for the three sentences you give.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I've updated it to use "if." I'm just curious if I can keep the structure of this sentence, changing only the ordinals.

Comment: I agree with Dan, _next_ for # 1and 3 and another for # 2 - another dessert not your another dessert. Alternatively _another_ for all the sentences. When you take another ... , if you have another ... , and When you have another ...

Comment: @markovchain No, I don’t think there is a way to do that. There is no catch-all word that fits every context, _especially_ not if you throw possessive determinatives into the mix.

Comment: @Dan I think "next" modifies the meaning, as instead of asking someone to call you on any subsequent flu shot (as Janus has accurately worded), you only ask them to call you on the next one.

Comment: @bookmanu Unfortunately "another" doesn't do the trick. Like "next," it reduces the numbers to the next most immediate one, rather than any subsequent one.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That's unfortunate. But thank you for the tip!

Comment: @markovchain - Neither "*next*' nor "*another*" precludes the possibility that there was more than one predecessor to the current iteration...

Comment: More by the way than anything... it's far more natural to _have_ a flu shot than _take_ it. That would make all your sentences use _have_. Then in every instance you could say, "When / If you have **another**..." Unless flu jabs are a series of injections, all part of one course, which would distinguish them from the other examples (but they're not, though, are they?) Then _follow-up_ might be useful. And don't neglect _next!_ (Edit: just saw Dan's comments saying the same thing.)

Comment: @Dan It's not the number of predecessors that "next" doesn't catch, but rather any subsequent successors. So for example, in the sentence "When you take your next flu shot, call me," if you've already had your third flu shot, then you might call me on your fourth, but not your fifth.

Comment: @markovchain - I cannot think of a single word.  However, last point, neither "*nex*t" nor "*another*" precludes the possibility that there *was* more than one predecessor to the current iteration, or that there may be one or more iterations in the future...

Answer (score -1):

You need to ditch using **"your"** in the latter example, then use a general article instead (**a/another/each**).  That immediately remedies the need to use the plural object (you already have "you" as the subject).

> When you take **a/another/each** subsequent flu shot, call me.

You can then consider using "**successive**" or "**sequential**" as alternative words denoting a generic second-third-fourth etc. These work fine the flu shot and with the other examples as well.

> When you take **a/another/each** **successive** flu shot, call me.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/successive

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sequential